# Why aren't D-amino acids used in proteins?

Tags: proteins, amino-acids

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are amino acids in biology homochiral?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/594/why-are-amino-acids-in-biology-homochiral)

Why are only L-amino acids used in protein construction, and not D-amino acids?

Comment: We already have [a question about the number of amino acids used in proteins](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/653/why-20-amino-acids-instead-of-64), so I edited your question to be only about the second part of your original question.

Comment: We also have [Why are amino acids in biology homochiral?](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/594/why-are-amino-acids-in-biology-homochiral?rq=1)

Comment: I personally (not base on Lab works) think, maybe structure of  translation related proteins and RNAs, is the cause of these. I'll carefully read your suggested links.

Comment: I could give citations of where D-amino acids are in fact used in proteins; however I'm not sure that would count as an answer to this question.